# Correct way to work with angular http calls and pass results to subscriber

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to make requests with a service in my application.  I want to pass the subscription on to the caller as is the usual behaviour, but I want to be able to also intercept the result, act on it **but not change it**, and carry on.

For example:

```
return this.http.get<LicenseKeyAndUsageModel>('api/license')
    .map(data => {
        this.hasValidLicenseKeyInternal.next(!data.isExpired);
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
            this.hasValidLicenseKeyInternal.next(false);
            return Observable.throw(new LicenseKeyMissingError());
        }
        else
            return Observable.throw(error);
    });
```

So in this case, I'm retriving the current license key, and updating a service level value as to whether the license key is valid, and still passing the result to the original subscriber.

Basically does this seem like the right approach? Or should I be doing something more 'Observable-y' like with multicast or something else?

Comment: I guess this is what you want instead of the `map`: https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/do.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `do()` operator (or `tap()` in RxJS 5.5) is intended to do.

It's true you could use `map()` for this as well but you need to remember to always return the original value. Also what you want seems to be a "side-effect" (you want to perform actions that affect application state outside of the observable chain) and this is what `do()` is made for.

Answer (score 1):

Rxjs `tap` is what you are after .

Check [`this`](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services) more info.

Sorry for not posting a big answer accessing thorough mobile.

Comment: Guess @martin already answered . Anyways if that link is of use